# how to get text from nested span when li is clicked, with simple javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't get jQuery yet, so javascript please. I need help adjusting my JS so it gets text from a nested span inside an li when clicked. i have it working now if you click the text, but id like it to work if you click the entire li without it getting the other nested elements (the image).

right now im working with the following html and js:

HTML:

```
<ul><li><img><span onclick="myfunction(this)">TEXT</span></li></ul> 

<input id="iSupervisorUserName" name="OBKey_WF_Manger_Supervisor_1" type="text" />
```

JS:

```
function myfunction(span) {
    var textInsideLi = span.innerHTML;
    var field = document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName");
    field.value = textInsideLi;
```

I would like the text from SPAN to be written to the input when the li is clicked, not just the span. I know I should move the onClick call from the span to the li, but how do I adjust the JS so it get only the text inside the span and not the IMG as well?

Comment: @Jonast92 Why avoid innerHTML? Add some information please, don't just spit out commands.

Comment: @GeenHenk Because what you want is text and not html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**here you go**

html

```
<ul><li onclick="myfunction(this)"><img><span>TEXT</span></li></ul>
```

js

```
function myfunction(li){
 document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName").value=
 li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent;
}
```

or

```
function myfunction(li){
 document.getElementById("iSupervisorUserName").value=
 li.childNodes[1].textContent;
}
```

anyway i would add an eventlistener to the ul or the li's.. as inline js is a mess if you wanna update the code later.also there is alot more code generated if you add `onclick="myfunction(this)"` on each li.

Comment: Not what OP requested as I read the question. Also no need to ask for explanations in your answer. It makes your answer a) worse and b) comments on downvotes are *not* mandatory

Answer (score 1):

You may get the inner `<span>` element with `.getElementsByTagName()` method:

*HTML:*

```
<ul><li onclick="myfunction(this);"><img><span>TEXT</span></li></ul>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function myfunction(li) {
    var span = li.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
        textInsideLi = span.textContent || span.innerText,
        field = document.getElementById('iSupervisorUserName');

    field.value = textInsideLi;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `innerHTML`??

Comment: @PeeHaa Because the OP is using `innerHTML`. The question was not about `innerHTML`, the question was about `<span>` element selection.

Comment: No the question was about getting the *text* of a span

Comment: @PeeHaa Better? In fact it shouldn't really matter speed-wise if you use `innerHTML` as a getter.

Comment: @Jonast92 Would you please be so kind to explain the OP why we all should avoid `innerHTML` of *getting* the tag content.